# Why is the relationship not created when using SpringBoot Neo4j Data?

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I wanted to add relationships between already created nodes using springboot neo4j data.
The phenomenon of deleting again after creation occurred

I wrote and ran the code as follows

```
@Node("Member")
@Getter
public class MemberNode {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private final Long memberId;

    @Property("name")
    private final String name;

    @Property("grade")
    @ConvertWith(converter = GradeTypeConverter.class)
    private final GradeType gradeType;

    @Relationship(type = "ACTED_IN", direction = Relationship.Direction.OUTGOING)
    private List<MemberRelationship> subRoles = new ArrayList<>();

    @Builder
    public MemberNode(Long memberId, String name, GradeType gradeType) {
        this.memberId = memberId;
        this.name = name;
        this.gradeType = gradeType;
    }
}
```

```
@RelationshipProperties
@Getter
@Setter
public class MemberRelationship {
    @RelationshipId @GeneratedValue Long id;
    @TargetNode
    private MemberNode person;

}
```

```
@Transactional
@GetMapping("/addSubRelationship")
public MemberNode addSubRelationship(String mainName, String subName){
    var main = memberRepository.findByName(mainName);
    var sub = memberRepository.findByName(subName);

    var relationship = new MemberRelationship();
    relationship.setPerson(sub);

    main.getSubRoles().add(relationship);

    memberRepository.save(main);

    return main;
}
```

http://localhost:8080/addSubRelationship?mainName=a&subName=b
And the result was as follows

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (hlp:`Member`) WHERE id(hlp) = $__id__ WITH hlp WHERE hlp IS NULL CREATE (memberNode:`Member`) SET memberNode = $__properties__ RETURN memberNode UNION MATCH (memberNode:`Member`) WHERE id(memberNode) = $__id__ SET memberNode += $__properties__ RETURN memberNode
```

```
MATCH (startNode)-[rel:`ACTED_IN`]->(:`Member`) WHERE (id(startNode) = $fromId AND NOT (id(rel) IN $__knownRelationShipIds__)) DELETE rel
```

```
MATCH (startNode)-[rel:`ACTED_IN`]->(:`Member`) WHERE (id(startNode) = $fromId AND NOT (id(rel) IN $__knownRelationShipIds__)) DELETE rel
```

why create and delete?

Comment: That's odd. Delete before create is the designed approach here. (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#query-creation.save) Just to point out that the delete is not something surprising.
BUT it should happen before the creation, of course. Do you have a simple setter for the list in place? During save SDN (might) create new instances when dealing with generated values. If it cannot set the relationship correctly, I wonder if this will get missed.

Comment: Just to be clear: It's the mixture of generated id that results in recreation of the object, the partial immutable object (Builder/Constructor) and in consequence the non-accessible `subRoles` list for SDN. If this solves your problem to adjust one of those bits, good. But I am still thinking about the wrong order, you are observing.